# How to uninstall gmail-desktop

Tags: 18.04, gmail

I installed gmail desktop app using following command,

```
sudo snap install gmail-desktop
```

But it was not letting me sign in, so I want to uninstall it. How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
sudo snap remove gmail-desktop
```

you could also use the gui method in the snap-store if it is installed. otherwise you can install it using

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```